# Relationship 1:N With EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this table

```
public class Unity
{
    public int Id {get;set }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class UsersRight
{
    public int Id {get;set }        
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Value{ get; set; }
}
```

I need a list of all unities that user have access.

I know to do this way:

```
var userRight = _DAL.UserRights(user).ToList();

var listUser = new List<Unity>; 

foreach (var item in userRight)
{ 
  listUser.add( new Unity(Name = item.Name, Id = item.Value));
}
```

How can I do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: Guys. You should utilize google before asking any questions. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I read this link before, the problem is that I don't have a link between the tables. I have a list with n records with the code of each Unity.

Comment: Your first line of code is a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)... just change it to `var userRight = _DAL.UserRights(user).ToList();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario, the **User** entity should have a list of Unities:

```
public virtual ICollection<Unity> Unities { get; set; }
```

and the **Unity** entity should have a User:

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

You can check [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) entity framework tutorial on how to configure one-to-many relationship.